# How to debug my Python code?

Tags: python

The purpose of my code it to intake a string from a user and turn into a non case-sensitive list. Then I need to intake a second string from the user then output the position of the second given string. This is my code:

```
UserSentence = input('Enter your chosen sentence: ') #this is where the user inputs their sentence
from string import punctuation #this 'fetches' the punctuation from the string
tbl=str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation})
UserSentence = UserSentence.lower().translate(tbl).split()#.split() turns the input sentence into a list,...
#...this will help to identify where a word appears...
#...in the sentence. The .lower() also turns the...
#...string into lowercase so it is not case sensitive.
UserWord = input('Enter a word from the sentence: ')#this is where the user inputs their word from the sentence
UserWord = UserWord.lower()#.lower() is used to make UserWord not case sensitive
for i in range(len(UserSentence)):
     if UserSentence (i) == UserWord:
         print ('Your chosen word appears in: ')
```

Comment: "Need help debugging my code please" - Tell us what is wrong.

Comment: Voting to close as no MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

To index a sequence you need to use `[]`

```
if UserSentence[i] == UserWord:
```

If you are trying to find which index (by word) their word is you can do

```
if UserWord in UserSentence:
    print('Your word is located at {}'.format(UserSentence.index(UserWord)))
```

Or similarly

```
try:
    print('Your word is located at {}'.format(UserSentence.index(UserWord)))
except ValueError:
    print('Your word is not in the sentence')
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of errors here:

1. If you're using Python 2, use `raw_input` for strings. In Python 3 `input` is okay.
2. Your `maketrans` call is weird
3. For looking up if a word is inside a list you don't any loops or own comparisons. Python can do that for you.
4. Please stick to [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It tells you how you should format your code so that it's easier to read.

---

Your rewritten and tested code:

```
from string import punctuation, maketrans

user_sentence = raw_input('Enter a sentence: ')
trans = maketrans("", "")
user_sentence = user_sentence.lower().translate(trans, punctuation).split()
user_word = raw_input('Enter a word from the sentence: ')
user_word = user_word.lower()
if user_word in user_sentence:
    print ('Your chosen word appears in the sentence.')
```

Comment: *"Use raw_input for strings."* Not since Python 3.x, this is only true back in 2.x